# What does it mean when you add terms inside the function parenthesis?

Tags: limits, notation

For example I have this:

$\lim\limits_{x \to x_o} f(x)$

and also

$\lim\limits_{u \to 0} f(x_0 + u)$

But i'm not really sure how to treat this second expression, is it a different function? what does it mean to add terms inside the parenthesis and take the limit?

Comment: $g(u)=f(x_0+u)$ is just a function like any other. What's the problem?

Comment: Also, if you let $x_0+u = x$, the two limits become equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the condensed form of the following : define the function $g(u) = f(x_0+u)$. So, to compute $g(u)$ for any $u$, we first compute $x_0+u$  and then apply $f$ on the output.

Then, the quantity $\lim_{u \to 0} f(x_0+u)$ means the same as $\lim_{u \to 0} g(u)$. So it is the limit of a different function $g$, but rather than write the definition of $g$ separately and use it, we just condense it in one line as $\lim_{u \to 0} f(x_0+u)$.

The "addition inside  the parentheses" is part of the definition of $g$, as was explained earlier.

As you go along, you will find more of these expressions, where you will have $$\lim_{some\  variable \to some\  value} \{\mathrm{something\  depending\  on \ f(x) \ and \ other\ things}\}$$

these all mean that the  "something depending on $f(x)$" is a *function* in the variable under the limit, and the quantity in question is the limit of this function as the variable approaches the given value.